# Mysql Join and echo all rows, with condition

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I need to join two tables, i already have the code for the first table:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM civicrm_event"; 

$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result) or die(mysql_error());
echo $row['title_en_US']. " - ". $row['id'];
echo "<br />";
```

I need to join it with another one called `civicrm_participant`, where i need to extract `contact_id`

The clause to select this tables is that:

`civicrm_event.id = civicrm_participant.event_id`

Then i need to echo `[title_en_US]` `[id]` `[contact_id]`
Help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[You should read joins in mysql](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html)

Do something like this:

```
$query = "SELECT ce.title_en_US, ce.id, cp.event_id FROM civicrm_event AS ce JOIN civicrm_participant AS cp ON ce.id=cp.event_id";
```

Comment: Hey thanks, i have now this query:
$query = "SELECT * FROM civicrm_event WHERE title_en_US='".addslashes($_GET["titles"])."' INNER JOIN civicrm_participant ON civicrm_event.id=civicrm_participant.event_id INNER JOIN civicrm_contact ON civicrm_participant.contact_id=civicrm_contact.id" ;

I am doing something wrong here... with this part...   WHERE title_en_US='".addslashes($_GET["titles"])."'
Can you please check it?

Comment: Your WHERE clause needs to be at the end of the query.